# Parse serialized date in Grails with proper time zone

Tags: javascript, json, grails

I'm trying to bind date in Grails App. In `application.yml` I have `databindings` for default JavaScript date formats:

```
  grails:
    databinding:
      dateFormats:
        - "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.S'Z'"
        - "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
```

In Groovy I'm creating object from params `def entity = new Entity(params)` and everything binds OK, but...

The problem is that I have wrong time zone in my Grails app, i.e.:

1. In AngularJS I'm creating new Date - `Thu Oct 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)` (this is string representation of `Date` object)
2. Next I'm sending it via `$http` service, JSON payload looks like this: `{ date: "2015-10-21T22:00:00.000Z", another: "another:, property: "property"  }`. 
   Date looks fine right now, `Z` at the end means it is UTC so `Thu Oct 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)` - 2 hours => `2015-10-21T22:00:00.000Z`
3. In Grails I'm doing `def entity = new Entity(params)` and here is problem, `entity.date` is equals to `Wed Oct 21 22:00:00 CEST 2015` which means that Groovy/Grails parsed string `2015-10-21T22:00:00.000Z` as CEST time zone not UTC

So how can I force Grails to load date with proper format?

PS
Both the web browser and computer is working with CEST time zone.

I'm using Grails 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper datetime string is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`.

In next versions this should be fixed and JavaScript datetime strings will be parsed via default parser.

More:

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9367
https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9368